# How to validate multidimensional array value in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have array like the below

```
data = [
  [product, billdetail],
  [avn, 200],
  [plioc,3000],
  [myjio,4000]
]


for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            var cube = data[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < cube.length; j++) {

                console.log("cube[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + cube[j]);
                 if(cube[j] === "")
                 {
                     alert('empty value');

                 }
            }
        }
```

I am doing empty validation here, i also want validation like product should have only alphabets and billdetail should have number only.so how can i achieve that here.please help me for the same.
(consider first row is table header and other rows are values.)

Comment: So you want to check each value against a set of rules? Can you clearly state what those rules are, and what you have tried so far

Comment: I am checking if any of the field is empty . i also required to check like product has only alphabet and billdetail has only number.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What approach do you think might be needed?

Comment: I have to iterate through each value using loop to check each value in the array corresponding to first row and validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one of is below.

```js
data = [
  ['product', 'billdetail'],
  ['avn', 213],
  ['plioc',3000],
  ['myjio',4000],
  ['inval1d produc1', 'invalidbill']
]

for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  let product = data[i][0];
  let bill = data[i][1];
  
  if (!product || !bill) {
    console.log('Product or Bill is null', product, bill);
  }
  
  if (!product.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)){
    console.log('Invalid Product:', product);
  }
  
  if (typeof(bill) !== 'number') {
    console.log('Invalid Bill:', bill);
  }    
}
```

Comment: create a zero based for loop, right now its throwing an error

Comment: I think the post mentioned that the first array in the `data` are headers right ? But anyways, what is the error ?

Comment: sorry, i dint read the header part , m good, also its not throwing any error, what i wanted to say was that it is skipping first record.